# How valid is to cast an integer to structure

Tags: c, c11

I have a code in which casting a integer to structure pointer throws a warning on gcc (linux)

```
typedef struct st {
    int a;
    char *b;
}st;
...
int handle;

int main() {
...
st *sptr = (st*)handle;
...
}
```

According to C11 spec

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

My question is
 can we cast an integer to structure pointer or we should look for other ways and keep this as last resort?

Comment: Please include the actual warning message. Probably the warning says that int and pointer have different size, which is important here.

Comment: Remember that a pointer is basically just an integer which is the address in memory of where the pointer is pointing. What the cast does is doing is taking the value of `handle` and using that as the address for the pointer to point to. It's not uncommon to do such things on embedded systems with fixed memory addresses.

Comment: Why do you want to do such a cast? On your platform `int` is likely smaller than a pointer. If you absolutely need something like this, use `intptr_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: If the size of `int` is the same as the size of a pointer it should work, but if not (which is most likely the case on your platform) it won't work.

Comment: You should definitely look for other ways. It's very easy to do this wrong. As stated in other comments, this is usually done when working very close to metal, and you must know what you are doing. If you are working on Linux user application, you most likely don't need this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to consider:

- It might not be possible to represent the result. `int` may not have the same representation as a pointer type for the given platform. This is why `uintptr_t` exists for cases such as this. `uintptr_t handle;` would make your code portable.
- The integer value must be something that can be interpreted as an aligned address for the given system.